# scala shapeless: default values for FromRecordArgs?

Tags: scala, shapeless

is it possible to work with default arguments when using the shapeless.FromRecordArgs trait?

In this little example

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.singleton._

trait original{
  def foo(i: Double = 1, j: Int = 2, k: String = "3") = (i,j,k)
}
object rec extends original with FromRecordArgs

rec.fooRecord('i ->> 11.0 :: 'j ->> 22 :: 'k ->> "33" :: HNil)
```

skipping any of the record arguments leads to a compile error like

```
Error:(11, 16) Implicit not found: shapeless.Ops.Selector[shapeless.::[Double with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("i")],Double],shapeless.::[String with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("k")],String],shapeless.HNil]], shapeless.labelled.FieldType[shapeless.tag.@@[Symbol,String("j")],Int]]. You requested an element of type shapeless.labelled.FieldType[shapeless.tag.@@[Symbol,String("j")],Int], but there is none in the HList shapeless.::[Double with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("i")],Double],shapeless.::[String with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("k")],String],shapeless.HNil]].
rec.fooRecord('i ->> 11.0 :: 'k ->> "33" :: HNil)
```

Support for default arguments would be really lovely to have, as it allows for flexible method wrappers (like possible in python with the double star **)